# scipy can not be installed on mac osx 10.10

Tags: python, macos, scipy, ipython

I couldn't install scipy on my Mac.

I installed the followings before scipy

- pip install --upgrade numpy
- brew install gfortran
- pip install scipy

I googled many solutions, but all of them not work for me.

## Errors on console (pip install scipy)

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: archive member: build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/libarpack_scipy.a(dlahqr.o) cputype (7) does not match previous archive members cputype (16777223) (all members must match)

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: archive member: build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/libarpack_scipy.a(slahqr.o) cputype (7) does not match previous archive members cputype (16777223) (all members must match)

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: archive member: build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/libarpack_scipy.a(zlahqr.o) cputype (7) does not match previous archive members cputype (16777223) (all members must match)

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: archive member: build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/libarpack_scipy.a(wrap_g77_abi_f.o) cputype (7) does not match previous archive members cputype (16777223) (all members must match)

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: archive member: build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/libarpack_scipy.a(wrap_accelerate_f.o) cputype (7) does not match previous archive members cputype (16777223) (all members must match)

error: Command "ranlib build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/libarpack_scipy.a" failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/n5/b8s03z3d7ljg5w74qxm_k4500000gn/T/pip_build_hsu-wei-cheng/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/n5/b8s03z3d7ljg5w74qxm_k4500000gn/T/pip-0Ik3cE-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/n5/b8s03z3d7ljg5w74qxm_k4500000gn/T/pip_build_hsu-wei-cheng/scipy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 185, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 51: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: `brew install scipy`? Or maybe `brew rm gfortran; brew install gcc` as it seems the compiler toolchain is broken.

Comment: @pv. not working, still got the same error

Comment: how did you install python? thru the pkg from python.org or homebew or any other?

Answer (score 0):

I installed Scipy in MacOS X normally with the use MacPorts. The instructions are provided here

http://www.scipy.org/install.html

I am not sure if you need all the modules that are included in the link definition, but anyway they are only basics.

Comment: i don't have port on 10.10

Answer (score 0):

I preferred to install scipy by **pip** but it failed.

This is a workaround by MacPorts.

- curl -O https://distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/MacPorts-2.3.1.tar.bz2
- ./configure
- make ; sudo make install
- make sure /opt/local/bin is in your environment variable **export PATH=/opt/local/bin:$PATH**
- sudo port install py27-scipy

Finished.